# openni-dev/ps-engine with rgbdslam_freiburg

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is there a way to use openni-dev and ps-engine packages with rgbdslam_freiburg?

There is a conflict with the file openni_launch.

openni_launch is used by rgbdslam, but when the newer openni-dev is installed, openni_launch and openni_camera need to be uninstalled.

How can I modify any files to use rgbdslam with the newer openni-dev and ps-engine?

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64399/openni-dev/ps-engine-with-rgbdslam_freiburg/) by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can just remove the dependency in rgbdslam's manifest? It isn't required to build it. If present you also need to remove the openni.launch include from the launch file you are using to start rgbdslam and start openni separately.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0